# Having issues with Git-TFS cloning repository

Tags: git, version-control, tfs, git-branch, git-tfs

I'm trying to migrate a repository from TFS 2010 to Git.

This is a relatively large TFS server. When I try and clone Trunk it says it does not exist. When I try one of the other branches it says I am going to clone the whole repository or too high in the repository path. If I go lower int he path it says it does not exist or same error.

Ultimately I need to migrate this entire project over to GIT. I am currently using git-tfs to try and do the migration.

I tried cloning a specific branch which appeared to work but only got a few revisions then when I did git tfs branch --init --all and it said it was not a branch.

Answer (score 0):

As explained [in the documentation](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/manage_tfs_branches.md), you can use the command `list-remote` to find the root branch of your TFS repository.

Before trying to clone all your branches, you must also be sure to have [converted all theses branches from "folder" to "branches"](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/Tfs-has-no-branches.md) (even the deleted ones). Seems to be part of your problem....

I hope that's your only problem because not all the (very strange) things TFS permit are supported in the released version. Perhaps you will have to look at [git-tfs forum](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues?direction=desc&sort=updated&state=open) where there is work in progress to support more cases. You will have to build your own version if that's the case.

PS: You haven't given us enough data to solve your problem. Update the question with the result of the `list-remote` command and the git-tfs command you used...

Comment: the "folder" to "branch" thing is already done. When I do list-remote it says no branches were found.

Comment: If you are REALLY sure of that, either you perhaps have a problem of rights or you are faced another horrible thing that Tfs permit to do and that you must investigate yourself (perhaps debugging with source code) :(